# psycopg2 issues with inserting a prepared JSONB object into postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a JSONB object that I want to insert into my database that also contains single quote characters. The example below is just trimmed to highlight my issue:

```
[{"name": "Moody's Analytics BBB Corp Bd ETF"}]
```

I have tried just dumping that JSON object to a string and inserting it, but the single ' wont allow that to work and when I try to execute (where detail is the JSON object):

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO schmea.table (id, detail) VALUES (?,?)", (sec_id, detail)
```

I get the following syntax error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: INSERT INTO schema.table (id, detail) VALUES (?,?)
                                                       ^
```

All of the solutions I've found so far suggest turning the JSON object into a string using json.dumps() but that wont work in my situation because of the single ' character in the name.

Any help is appreciated here.

Edit: Was told that the proper bind is %s not ? but that changes the error to:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'
```

edit 2:

SOLUTION:

Using the correct %s binds and using json.dumps(detail) fixed the issue.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO schmea.table (id, detail) VALUES (%s,%s)", (sec_id, json.dumps(detail))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As in many things the docs have the answer [JSON](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json).

Answer (score 2):

The way to pass bind variables to psycopg2 is with `%s`, not `?`.

Comment: I got it mixed with pyodbc. But in changing to %s i get the error 

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'
```

Comment: Try sending it a JSON or just a plain string. PostgreSQL knows how to implicitly convert a `text` to `jsonb`. Or even use explicit conversion: `%s::jsonb`.

Comment: Your answer got me half way there. After using the correct bind using json.dumps(detail) solved my issue. Thanks for the help!